# Construction of unowallet url

Tags: wallet, e-wallet, hash

I just tried to use unowallet.
It seem that the private key is somehow encoded into the url. 
Isn't it some known type of representation?
Wouldn't it be possible to create an url for my private key?

Or maybe its just the seed of the bitcoin address generator.

My only observation is that it is not a base58 because there are 'l' and 'O's, it may not be base64 because it does have bad number of characters (but maybe '=' are ommited).

e.g:

URL: https://uno-wallet.com/wallet/WXG7M59EniYuAm39ildMv7lUDc2L5khVLDpMPic2dOo1mJDiLJ

Address: 1BjECXazZUZdd8zAj7VoxppoBA73aZ1KrX

Private key: 5JWXyvz2DcEKQFm7pa6j8Gp1M5A8cgNhx4F2ZjM2R14MHy3D2NQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hidden feature of unowallet

https://uno-wallet.com/key/5JWXyvz2DcEKQFm7pa6j8Gp1M5A8cgNhx4F2ZjM2R14MHy3D2NQ

gives you access to your wallet with the private key after "key/" in the URL.

This can be used for any private key, not just the ones used on unowallet.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably hashed. Any URL is valid.

https://uno-wallet.com/wallet/0